# Convert vowels in string to uppercase

Tags: swift

How do I make vowels in a String uppercase in Swift?

I tried this:

```
func makeVowelsUpperCase(sentence:String)-> String {
    
    var result = String()
      
    var vowels = "aeiou"
    
    for i in vowels{
    
        if sentence.contains(i){
           result = sentence(i.uppercased())
        }
    }
    
  return result }

makeVowelsUpperCase(word: "this is my house")
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues going on:

1. `for i in vowels` your `for` loop is iterating over the vowels. Within each loop body, you choose whether to keep your vowel or not depending on whether it's in the sentence or not.

   The result of this is that your result string could only ever be something like `"AEIOU"`, `"AIU"`, etc. (i.e., it will only be a string of length 0-5, only containing some subset of those vowels)
2. `sentence(i.uppercased())` This part just doesn't make sense. `sentence` is a `String`, but by using parenthesis on it, it looks like you're tryign to call it, as if it were a function (but it's not). Hence the error: "error: incorrect argument label in call (have 'word:', expected 'sentence:')"
3. You're reassigning `result` in the loop body, which means your `result` could only ever contain one character. Instead, you should make one intermediate value once, and append onto it from there.
4. The way you're trying to call `makeVowelsUpperCase` (with an argument label of `word:`) doesn't match the way it's declared (with an argument label of `sentence:`).

I think this is what you had in mind:

```
func makeVowelsUpperCase(sentence: String) -> String {
    var result = String()
    let vowels = "aeiou"
    
    for char in sentence {
        if vowels.contains(char) {
            result.append(char.uppercased())
        } else {
            result.append(char)
        }
    }
    
    return result
}

makeVowelsUpperCase(sentence: "this is my house")
```

There's a few other issues I'd point out:

1. `vowels` is declared mutable (`var` instead of `let`). Why would the set of vowels be mutable? They should always just be `"aeiou"` (for English, at least).
2. The loop variable is called `i`, which is conventional for a loop variable that's an index of some array, but in this case, it's a `Character`.
3. The keyword label, `sentence` is a little misleading. There's no real requirement that the input be a sentence. It could be a word, or a paragraph, and everything would still work as normal.
4. This `for` loops is just implementing a mapping operation, where an input sequence (the characters of the input) is mapped into the output sequence (the potentially uppercased characters of the output) using some transformation (uppercase if vowel). This is precisely what [`Array.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) is for.

   There's just one catch here. As it turns out, in some languages, the uppercased version of one character might actually be multiple characters. To account for this, [`Character.uppercased()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127023-uppercased) doesn't actually return a `Character`, it returns a `String`.

   To cope with this, we need to use [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126947-flatmap) instead of `map`, which will have the effect of joining these strings returned as a result of each character-upper-casing operation.

Here's how I might right this:

```
func uppercaseVowels(_ input: String) -> String {
    let vowels = "aeiou"
    
    let newChars = input.flatMap { char in
        vowels.contains(char) ? char.uppercased() : String(char)
    }
    
    return String(newChars)
}

print(uppercaseVowels("this is my house"))
```

Comment: thanks for the corection, i knew it was not working i just wanted to represente what i had.

Comment: better to use a set `let vowels: Set = .init("aeiou")`

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not so sure. The small-string optimization probably makes it faster. I'm busy today, but if you have time to benchmark it, I'd be interested to see the results

Comment: @slowTurtle That's good, that's exactly how this site expects questions to be asked. It demonstrates your effort, where your confusion is, and gives us something concrete to talk about

Comment: I mean in general. You can keep it as a string if you would like to.

Comment: I would probably use `joined()` instead of `flatMap`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
func makeVowelsUpperCase(_ sentence:String)-> String {
    var result = sentence
    let vowels = "aeiou"
    vowels.forEach {
        result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: "\($0)", with: "\($0)".uppercased())
    }
    return result 
}
```

Call

```
let str = makeVowelsUpperCase("this is my house")  
print(str) // thIs Is my hOUsE
```

Comment: I don't think this actually really helps much. It solves the problem, but doesn't teach what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple code like below :

```
var word : String = "this is my house "
var vowels = "aeiou"

let result = word.map { vowels.contains($0) ? String($0).uppercased() : String($0) }
            .joined()
print(result)
```

OUTPUT :

```
thIs Is my hOUsE
```

In a function :

```
func uppercaseVowels(_ input: String) -> String {

    let result = input.map { vowels.contains($0) ? String($0).uppercased() : String($0) }
                .joined()

    return result
}

print(uppercaseVowels(word))
```

Comment: Why `enumerated()`? You only ever use the `element` and not the `offset`.

Comment: Yeap. Enumeration is not neccessary here. Fixed

Comment: no need to initialize a new string with the character. Character has already an uppercased method which returns a string